# SQL Syntax error when trying to insert array values of a Datatable

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datatable

I am having a SQL syntax error when I try to Insert in mysql database array values of a datatable named 'table'.

```
ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.0.27-community-nt]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right.
```

Datatable = table;

Here's the code:

```
 for (int x = 0; x < table.Rows.Count; x++)
   {
      conn.Open();
      OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO jevslimporttemp(JevSLImportTempCode, JevSLImportTempDescription, JevSLImportTempAmount)VALUES('" + table.Rows[x][0].ToString() + "','" + table.Rows[x][1].ToString() + "','" + Convert.ToDouble(table.Rows[x][2].ToString()) + "');", conn);
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      conn.Close();
   }
```

Comment: Edit the question and print out the string after variable substitution.

Comment: What you get error just mention here

Comment: And while you are at it, make your query readable without having to scroll horizontally.

Comment: I just tried to output the strings in a messagebox and it works fine. But the moment I insert it on the database using the query string, I get an error. Can someone tell me what part of the query was wrong?

Comment: What you get error just mention here

Comment: ERROR : ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.0.27-community-nt]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right.

Comment: @JasonX In third values try without single quotes...

Comment: print `command.commandText` so we can review the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely have values in your variable interfering with the sql, like a single quote or question mark. You should parameterize your query.

```
OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO jevslimporttemp(JevSLImportTempCode, JevSLImportTempDescription, JevSLImportTempAmount)VALUES(?, ?, ?);", conn);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("JevSLImportTempCode", table.Rows[x][1].ToString());
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("JevSLImportTempDescription", table.Rows[x][1].ToString());
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("JevSLImportTempAmount", Convert.ToDouble(table.Rows[x][2].ToString()));
```

Comment: This seems to be the right fix to my problem... Thanks sir for the help... God bless

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all three of your fields are not string type. From the field names my guess is the third field is numeric. Try without quote for the third field:

```
OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO jevslimporttemp(JevSLImportTempCode, JevSLImportTempDescription, JevSLImportTempAmount)VALUES('" + table.Rows[x][0].ToString() + "','" + table.Rows[x][1].ToString() + "'," + Convert.ToDouble(table.Rows[x][2].ToString()) + ");", conn);
```